# How to stop web-mode from reindenting after yank?

Tags: indentation, web-mode, yank

I'm editing this code:

```
callFunction({
    x: somearray,
});
```

Then I want to extract `somearray` to be a variable with a copy.  I cut `somearray` and delete the colon, then enter (`_` is the cursor):

```
const x = [..._
callFunction({
    x
});
```

Then yank, and the super helpful web-mode screws up my code:

```
const x = [...somearray_
    callFunction({
        x
    });
```

Then I close the bracket and have to reindent the function call expression.

How to disable this autoindenting after yank?

Disabling `electric-indent-local-mode` does not help.  Neither does setting `electric-indent-inhibit` to `t`.  Searching for "web-mode disable auto-indent" does not lead to a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to try setting `web-mode-enable-auto-indentation` to `nil`:

```
(setq web-mode-enable-auto-indentation nil)
```

[An issue](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/894) was filled about this a while ago (and there were probably other ones, it's not worth searching for these). It doesn't seem to be documented well, so it's not easy to find the option.

Comment: Such an obvious thing.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks - how the `web-mode` author him/herself didn't go crazy yanking some data on an incomplete line...  (to then do something about it, like have this "feature" disabled by default!)