# web-mode turn off auto indent on yank

Tags: indentation, web-mode, electric-indent

How to turn off auto indent on yank in web mode?

As far as I understand, I must call `remove-hook` with the name of the hook and the function. But how too find them?

Comment: This question has already been answered in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50643/29337

Comment: @wosc It worked, thank you.

Comment: @Stefan Yes, I marked the question as a duplicate, but don't want to remove it completely.